# What's firebase / firestore timezone

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Q1. May I know what's the timezone that firebase server and web console is?

Q2. Using FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to save data, how could I convert the timestamp to user timezone?

Q3. Could I configure timezone for firebase server?

Q4. While refer to firebase web console usage info, what's the timezone it showing?
What is the latency for latest usage to appear on web console usage section?

Comment: Timestamps represent a moment in time that's the same everywhere on earth, similar to unix epoch time.  In the console, timestamps are shown in the timezone of the user's clock as defined by the computer's system settings.  So, it could appear different for people around the world, depending on how their computer is configured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timezone of Firestore Timestamp is in UTC, if you want to convert that timezone to the timezone your client has do this.

You can set the timezone with `DateFormat()` and parse the timestamps result with that timezone.

```
    Date date = new Date(timestamp);    
    DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    Log.d("Date:",""+utcFormat.format(date));
```

Regarding Q3, I think since it's from a server-side perspective, you can't change it.

About Q4, I don't really know the latency.

**Edit**: I have found some info about Q3

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

If you are doing Functions, you can setup the timezone.

Comment: Firebase serverTimeStamp() is a number

Comment: @cutiko Actually, a Timestamp type object in Cloud Firestore has two numbers, seconds and nanoseconds, which are combined for the timestamp to have nanosecond precision.