# Parse Firestore timestamp to Flutter DateTime considering UTC

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a timestamp in my firestore collection like this `February 1, 2022 to 00:00:00 UTC+1`.
In my flutter app, when I parse the date using `DateTime.parse(firestore_timestamp.toDate().toString())`, it comes like this `2022-01-31 23:00:00.000` which means it didn't take in count the `UTC+1` but the **GMT time instead**. Even `DateTime.parse(firestore_timestamp.toDate().toLocal().toString())` doesn't convert to local. I checked and it's `firestore_timestamp.toDate()` that parses the **timestamp** in GMT. Is there any other solutions to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

Firestore timestamps don't have a local timezone attached to them. They are all UTC. What you see in the console is just the formatting of the date in the timezone configured on your computer. It will change as the configuration of the clock changes in your OS.

In general, there should never be a need to parse the string version of a timestamp.  You should always assume that timestamps are UTC.  If you need to display something different, then you should use a library to format it according to the end user's preference.

See also:

- [can I change timezone saved in Firestore timestamp field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241230/can-i-change-timezone-saved-in-firestore-timestamp-field)
- [What's firebase / firestore timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645880/whats-firebase-firestore-timezone)
- [Firestore Timestamp.toDate() returns date in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507582/firestore-timestamp-todate-returns-date-in-utc)

Comment: Thanks, I though there were an issue with the conversion of Timestamp to DateTime until I realize that the emulator was set with a different timeZone from my computer. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem, I were using an emulator where the timeZone is different from my current timeZone, so be sure to set your machine/emulator timeZone correctly before.